# Openshift Default Code doesn't work with local node executable

Tags: javascript, node.js, openshift

I just started using OpenShift to host a node.js website and I wanted to test it locally (rather than pushing changes and restarting the server everytime I want to test my code). Unfortunately despite re-installing node just this morning it doesn't seem to like the default code that openshift ships with. In particular, when I run `nodejs --use_strict start.js` from my command line, it gives errors about using const (as it should) using let (not sure why) and using the ` symbol (not sure how to fix).

Here is the code that OpenShift ships with:

```
const cluster = require('cluster'),
      stopSignals = [
        'SIGHUP', 'SIGINT', 'SIGQUIT', 'SIGILL', 'SIGTRAP', 'SIGABRT',
        'SIGBUS', 'SIGFPE', 'SIGUSR1', 'SIGSEGV', 'SIGUSR2', 'SIGTERM'
      ],
      production = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production';

let stopping = false;

cluster.on('disconnect', function(worker) {
  if (production) {
    if (!stopping) {
      cluster.fork();
    }
  } else {
    process.exit(1);
  }
});

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  const workerCount = process.env.NODE_CLUSTER_WORKERS || 4;
  console.log(`Starting ${workerCount} workers...`);
  for (let i = 0; i < workerCount; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
  if (production) {
    stopSignals.forEach(function (signal) {
      process.on(signal, function () {
        console.log(`Got ${signal}, stopping workers...`);
        stopping = true;
        cluster.disconnect(function () {
          console.log('All workers stopped, exiting.');
          process.exit(0);
        });
      });
    });
  }
} else {
  require('./app.js');
}
```

With similar code in other files (app.js, and utils/*.js) which run the site itself. My question is how do I get my node implementation to run their code locally, and if I can't get it to, how I should change their code to work (can I just delete all 'const's, change ` to ' and 'let' to 'var')?

Comment: Jea u can just change the const and let to var. With the \` symbol just use stringconcatination.

Comment: Or you could use an never node version local.

Comment: Thats the thing, as far as I can tell I'm running the newest version of node. When I run `node --version` I get v5.11.0 which means it *should* work, no?

Comment: I guess its just a typo in this comment but it could be that:  node --version !== nodejs --version

Comment: I don't think that maintaining different code versions for local development and deployment is worthwhile. @LambdaBeta, it seems that you are using the [Node.js (latest)](https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/243-node-js-latest) quick-start. It's using node version from https://semver.io/node/stable by default (which is 5.10.1 atm, so your 5.11.0 should be fine). I'm able to run the quick-start locally with node 5.10.1 (`node --use_strict start.js`); could you include the full error output you are getting in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Include 'use strict'; in both app.js and start.js and it will run locally as expected.